# fetch the height of an element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a pagination function in an angular app. I have got a `<div>` container, that has a size depending on the window size. In that container, there is my list. Now this list has to be split into n pages to avoid having a scrollbar. Everything works fine yet, except for the fact, that I have to hardcode the height of a list element.

What I need to calculate the number of pages for the pagination is:

- The length of the list (number of list items),
- the height of the container (refreshed on each `window.onresize`) and
- the height of one list element.

I am able to keep track of the list length. I am also able to fetch the height of the container and to refresh that value on `window.onresize`.

But I am not able to fetch the height of a list element in the DOM tree.

I've written a directive, to pass the scope and selector names from a template into my code:

```
<div class="multicolumn-list" ng-controller="mymodule.listtypes.multicolumn.controller">
    <pagination-updater space-selector=".list-spacer" item-selector="li:first" page-size-model="listmodel.pageSize" listen="listmodel.list.items">
        <div class="list-spacer">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in listmodel.pageItems">
                    <a ng-click="mymodule.selectItem(item)">{{item.id}} ({{item.type}})</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </pagination-updater>
</div>
```

My directive looks like this right now:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('shared.directives.paginationUpdater', ['shared.services.dimensions']);
angular.module('shared.directives.paginationUpdater').directive('paginationUpdater', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: {
            'post': function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {

                var pageSizeModelName = iAttrs.pageSizeModel;

                var setPageSize = function () {

                    var spaceElement = iElement.find(iAttrs.spaceSelector);
                    var itemElement = iElement.find(iAttrs.itemSelector);

                    console.log(itemElement.height());
                };
                scope.$watch('$parent.' + iAttrs.listen, function () { setPageSize(); }, true);
                scope.$on('windowResized', function () { setPageSize(); });
                setPageSize();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

When I run my application, the list is empty, so there is no `<li>` and `itemElement.height()` returns `0`. Then my list becomes updated, then the `setPageSize()` will be called again, but `itemElement.height()` still returns `0`. I think it is, because this code is executed before the list will be rendered into the page. Do you have any idea, how I can archive this? Right now, I have the height of an element hardcoded and the best compromise I see is to pass the height value from the template to the directive:

```
<div class="multicolumn-list" ng-controller="mymodule.listtypes.multicolumn.controller">
    <pagination-updater space-selector=".list-spacer" item-height="{{main.zoomFactor}} * 26 + 1" page-size-model="listmodel.pageSize" listen="listmodel.list.items">
        <div class="list-spacer">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in listmodel.pageItems">
                    <a ng-click="mymodule.selectItem(item)">{{item.id}} ({{item.type}})</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </pagination-updater>
</div>
```

But then still I have to change the templates if we have a change in the style sheets. I also don't want to write a timeout. Maybe there is an event angular fires after updating the DOM tree?

Answer (score 0):

A little hack you could do to get around this is to have a 'dummy' list item on load. Unfortunately it does need to be visible at render time. So you could do something like this, that way you have a `<li>` Item rendered and the `&nbsp;` should be enough to get it to have some height without any content being visible to the user while your data is being fetched.

```
<ul>
  <li class="dummy-item"
      ng-show="!listMode.pageItems.length"><a>&nbsp;</a></li>
  <li ng-repeat="item in listmodel.pageItems">
      <a ng-click="mymodule.selectItem(item)">{{item.id}} ({{item.type}})</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know this is an old question but hope it still helps.